# Two routes to the same network through different interfaces

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing

For a bridge that is defined as

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge-ifaces enp0s8
        bridge-ports enp0s8
        up ifconfig enp0s8 up

iface enp0s8 inet manual
```

the os sets up the 2 routes on the interface `up`:

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.134
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.134
```

But if one tries to make the same up manually with:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel src 192.168.1.134
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel src 192.168.1.134
```

then the second command fails with `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`.

**The question:**

Does the kernel cheat or there is some key I missed in my `ip route add` commands?

It's not about whether this configuration makes sense or not, it's about "how the kernel could do that".

Comment: Did you intentionally invert the two lines?

Comment: @JuliePelletier I did not: the order does not change the outcome. In either case it won't add the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge) which says (after the first example):

> You will note that auto eth0 and iface eth0 inet manual are not in the file. This is because br0 will bring up the components assigned to it.

It makes no sense to configure the Ethernet adapters connected to a bridge as they simply share the bridge's IP address.

The reason you were not able to add the route manually is because you didn't reproduce the steps in the init scripts.  If you set an IP on `enp0s8`, then the system will allow you to add the route.  Again note that this is wrong and will make routing more complicated (especially if you do advanced routes, forwarding or NATing).

To reproduce the system's init scripts, after deleting all relevant routes and removing the bridge if it already exists:

```
brctl addbr br0
ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.1.0/24
ifconfig br0 192.168.1.0/24
```

This will get `ip route` to output both routes.  If you add `enp0s8` to the bridge then that will not work anymore.  You are simply getting a slightly abnormal result from an obviously bad configuration.

Comment: My question was: how was the kernel able to add 2 routes to the same network through different interfaces. The question is not about whether it makes sense or not, but about whether it's a kernel that used internal mechanism not exposed to the userland or I used the `ip route` command wrong.

Comment: I updated my question to make it even more clear.

Comment: "If you set an IP on enp0s8, then the system will allow you to add the route." --- the address is there on both interfaces, and it does not allow it: `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: I really sorry, but it again not what I asked: my question is, how the kernel could add 2 routes to the same network (it makes no sense, and is not possible (?) through the `ip route`).

Comment: @zerkms: It only does so when they are not bridged yet, as I explained.

Comment: Yes. But I was curious - why it's not possible to make the same routes up manually. Under exactly the same circumstances: when you have an interface and a bridge both with IP addresses assigned. Not sure how I express it clearly, but: the question is, why I cannot do the same manually and whether the kernel uses some sort of "backdoor" for that. I understand **why** it does it, the problem is **how** it does it.

Comment: I showed you how to do it.

Comment: The only reasonable place I could see having the code to ensure the route is not duplicated would be to in bridge controls but that would have the negative effect or requiring cross-dependencies which at best would have a minimal performance impact.  Like I said in my answer, this is a slightly bad behavior caused by a clearly bad configuration.  The system would let you have two adapters with the same IP if you don't bridge them, but handling them properly would be quite complicated for nothing.